# How can I resolve an" ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" issue in a Django project?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Chapter 18 of Python Crash Course, and have started over from scratch twice already, all 53 steps. (A very educational process)

The program was working fine until I tried to add the code for individual pages. Now, it won't run at all.

It keeps saying that `views aren't defined`. I've tried every suggestion I've found for similar issues without success and double checked all the elements.

Here is the code for my `urls.py` and `views.py`.

Any information/suggestions on how to resolve this  would be greatly appreciated.

```
"""Defines URL patterns for learning_logs"""

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>>/',views.topic,name = 'topic'),
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
    path('topics/',views.topics, name='topics'),
    ]

from .models import Topic
from django.shortcuts import render

def topics(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics':topics}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topics.html',context)


def index(request):
    return render(request,'learning_logs/index.html')

def topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id= topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic,'entries':entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html',context)
```

Here is the long error message I receive in the terminal:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/learning_log/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
NameError: name 'views' is not defined
```

Comment: Are `urls.py` and `views.py` in the same directory? And can you paste the full error (stacktrace) here that you get in the terminal/console?

Comment: Thank you for responding! Yes, the two files are in the same directory.  I'll edit the question and add the full error message. It's long and difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the last few lines of the traceback:

```
File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/learning_log/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
NameError: name 'views' is not defined
```

This is a pretty common error; it usually means you forgot an import statement. You've combined your urls.py and models.py files in this post, but it looks like you have `from . import views` at the top of your urls.py file. It's also odd that it would complain about `views` being undefined in the `topics/` path, but not in the two paths defined before that.

You said that you've started the project over several times. My best guess is that the urls.py file from a previous attempt is still being used. I can think of a number of ways this might happen. Here's the path to the urls.py file that's being used:

```
File "/Users/andreawalker/Desktop/learning_log/learning_log/urls.py"
```

Is this the urls.py file from your current attempt? If not, close out all open terminals, editors, etc. Then open a terminal and navigate to the folder where your current attempt lives. Activate the virtual environment in that directory, run your project, and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried it, but got the same error.  I don't mind starting again from scratch, but I'm wondering if there is an error in the order of the steps given in the book.

Comment: I'm the author of the book, and no one else has asked about this error. I usually hear pretty quickly if there's something in the book that's no longer working. If you can post your whole project somewhere like GitHub I could look at it and help sort it out. If you want to email me a zip file of your project, everything except the ll_env directory, I'd be happy to look. I'm ehmatthes at gmail. StackOverflow is a hard place to diagnose issues in a large project like this if you're not clear about exactly what parts of the project to share.

Comment: Thank you. This is the fourth time I've started from scratch, and each time as I update, it crashes and shuts down the server, saying that something can't be defined. I'll e-mail the project folder, without the ll_env directory. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same `ImportError` problem. If you are using Sublime Text Editor, I noticed it happened because I was probably trying to build my views.py file. Just go to the 'file' menu of Sublime Text Editor and select 'Save All' instead of building your scripts. Then you issue `python manage.py runserver` command in a terminal session and it runs.